# Named Anchors (#like-this) Only Work First Time in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

In Chrome and Safari, clicking on a link to a named anchor (`<a href="#like-this">Hash Link<a>`) only works the first time. Subsequent clicks do not snap to the referenced element. This works as expected in Firefox. I was able to find a [chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30387) that looks relevant, but no workaround was provided and no fix appears to be forthcoming. Do you know of a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to do this is to capture the anchor clicks, find the coordinates of the target and use `window.scrollTo(x,y)`.

There are some bits of code [out there](http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery) that will do this for you, like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#services">Jump to services</a>

<div id="services">

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply scrolling to the element is an accessibility issue. When clicking a real anchor link, the browser moves the focus navigation start point so that keyboard users can continue navigating through the page. Simply scrolling to the element does not do this, it continues from the link, so this solution is effectively useless for keyboard/screen reader users. One solution is documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544257/13186118. We cannot currently move the focus navigation start point. See https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5326

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if there were a non-js solution for this issue, but that seems unlikely.

I was just about to use javascript like:

```
  location.hash = '#actual-destination-invalid-to-fix-webkit'
  location.hash = '#actual-destination'
```

But I think the answer provided by Diodeus is a little less hackey, without being too complex.